# Story involving teenager being recruited to travel to different worlds

Tags: story-identification

I read this story about five years ago (so make it about 2009) and the book (from the library) was reasonably tattered, but I'd say only 5 to 10 years old (this is just a rough guess).
This was a novel, I *think* about 300 pages, but again I don't recall it very well so that could also be completely wrong.  I do remember it wasn't a huge tome though.

Most importantly: the narrative.  This story involved a teenage boy who was recruited by a man on a motorbike to help in some expedition; I think they were part of a group involved in some sort of missions against an evil group (again I can't recall exactly what).  This man (who I think was his Uncle 'Bob' or something like that) took him to a subway station and they only just made it to a portal to another world.  I think I'm missing a huge portion of the story, but at the end I recall they ended up in another world (through a portal of some description).  It was an ice world with a pre-Industrial civilization.

The key part of this novel that was members of this group trying to thwart the antagonists could only use a dog whistle; nothing else **from a different world/time period could be used in that place**.  This was emphasized regularly and when the main character went to the ice world, he got into considerable grief with his mentor (the Uncle Bob character) for using a torch from his original time period.

I think it was set about the early 2000s.  One last piece of information I recall was that this guy was regularly going on about three girls who were perfect at everything they touched.  He had a crush on one called Courtney.

Sorry for the vague details at the beginning, but hopefully the narrative description could prove useful.  Thanks ;)

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/833710.The_Merchant_of_Death? Not a great match.

Comment: @Richard you're a genius!  That's exactly the book.  If you post it as an answer I'll of course mark it as correct.  Thanks so much :D

Comment: The word "perfects" doesn't appear in any of the books in the series.

Comment: @Richard Hmmm that's strange.  It's definitely the right book.  Perhaps my mind's playing tricks on me or something.  I'll remove that from the descriptor.  Cheers ;)

Comment: He does use the word perfect an unreasonably high number of times, like 10+ per novel

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243568/series-where-the-protagonist-jumps-through-portals-to-stop-someone-messing-up-th (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "[The Merchant of Death](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/833710.The_Merchant_of_Death)" by D.J. MacHale, the first book of the [Pendragon/Halla](http://www.goodreads.com/series/42782-pendragon) series.

The book revolves around a young boy named Bobby Pendragon whose uncle takes him (and his best friend Mark and his major crush, Courtney Chedwynde) into a magical world called Denduron.

His uncle gives him a whistle to help ward off local animals known as quigs but he ends up using a flashlight from home as a supplementary weapon, against his uncle's advice

> This may be the last journal I write to you, Mark and Courtney. If it
>   is, then please know that it wasn’t your fault about the flashlight.
>   All you did was help out a friend. The blame is all mine. If you don’t
>   hear from me again, then please know I did everything I could to undo
>   the mess I created. I may not be successful, but at least I tried.
>   Thank you for reading this, and for being my friends.